# How to store decimal numbers in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, floating-point, decimal

I tried to store decimal number, but couldn't. It's Office 2019. I tried both number types, and different "format". One format had some zero's show up after a comma, but could not enter decimal number, it was rounded. I was thinking about storing gps coordinates.

Comment: *I tried to store decimal number* Show some examples. Suitable datatype depends on the values to be stored in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [data types](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-30ad644f-946c-442e-8bd2-be067361987c) !

Have you tried `double` ? it handles most decimal numbers up to fifteen significant digits.

Comment: I have a swedish version of Access, and I found the double type under Fältstorlek ("fieldsize"). So I don't know if that is corresponding to your data types.

Comment: I worked at a bank and was surprised to find that they used integers to store money amounts instead of a floating point datatype because of the risk of calculation errors.